# Methodology of modelling sparse events

Tags: binomial-distribution, sparse, poisson-process

Let us say that we have a process that generates sequences of the following form:

$$S=[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,\mathbf{4},0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,\mathbf{1},0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,\mathbf{3},0,0,0,\mathbf{5},0,0,0]$$

What is the best way to model something like this?

Since $\mathrm{E}(x)$ is small and the number of samples is low one would be tempted to model this using a Poisson distribution. However, this seems quite limiting as give that a Poisson is fully described with the same parameter $\mathrm{E}(x)$, so the same Poisson could model generate another sequence with more zero events and higher values, which I consider been drawn for a different process.

Would it make more sense to first model the non-zero occurrences with a Binomial, draw from it and them model the number corresponding to the non zero occurrences with a Poisson?

Comment: This is a common procedure and is known as a 'hurdle model' , or a zero-inflated model (see Zuur et al. 2009 Mixed Effects Models and their Extensions for an easy discussion with ecological examples in R).

Comment: Have you tried to see if you can use zero-inflated Poisson?

Comment: When you say 'model' what is it you're interested in modelling, exactly? The intervals between non-zero-values? The process as a time series? This as a response in some model which has a predictor? Just the univariate mean of this process regarded as independent observations? The whole distribution of the process regarded as independent observations?

Comment: Thank you guys!
Seeing the definition of zero-hurdle models, I am quite confident that this could be modelled using a zero-inflated Poisson process.